# Error when trying to deploy Lightning Page: "Error: You can't change a Lightning Page's associated template"

Tags: deployment, metadata, xml, template, flexipages

Relatively new to the SFDC world and I've come across this issue when trying to deploy Lightning pages to a new sandbox. When deploying my lightning page via workbench I get the following error:

```
Error: You can't change a Lightning Page's associated template
```

I've tried deleting the Flexipage entirely in my target org and then redeploying but I'm still seeing the same results. Any input on this would be appreciated!

Hoping that I don't have to go and recreate my pages in the target org every time I make a UI change.